# has_and_belongs_to_many or polymorphic has_many :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, polymorphic-associations

I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to set this association up.

I have 3 models: Musicians, Bands and Managers. Each of those can have a certain "level" associated with them (stress, happiness, etc).

But I'm not sure how to correctly associated my Levels model with the other 3.

Do I need some sort of has_many :through that's polymorphic? And how on earth do I set that up? Is there some other type of associated I need?

[image]

Comment: To clarify, is a Level associated with say, an instance of a Musician, or all Musicians?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the case where you're defining attributes that can be assigned to a particular class of model, then you probably want to use a more conventional approach. Instead of `kind` use something like `record_type` and build a scope on that instead.

That way what you'd do to fetch them is create an accessor method, not a relationship, between any of your entities and this column. Something like this:

```
def levels
  Level.for_record_type(self.class)
end
```

The `for_record_type` is a scope:

```
scope :for_record_type, lambda { |record_type|
  where(:record_type => record_type.to_s)
}
```

There's no convention for associating models with classes instead of instances of other models.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this would be a polymorphic association:

```
class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :leveled, :polymorphic => true # maybe there's a better word than "leveled"
end

class Musician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :levels, :as => :leveled
end
```

You'll need to add a `leveled_type` and `leveled_id` to your Levels table.